# jQuery .load refresh causing page shrink

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**What I'm Working With**
I have two Google Charts that are created with a php script and loaded onto a page with jQuery load. When the load function runs every 5 seconds, it reloads the chart into a div.

**How the charts are reloaded**

```
  <script>
      window.setInterval(function(){
          $("#3").load("3.php");
      }, 5000);
  </script>
  <script>
      window.setInterval(function(){
          $("#4").load("4.php");
      }, 5000);
  </script>
```

**My Issue**
I have identified the issue, I just need a good way to fix it. When the chart is loaded in every 5 seconds, the chart div's quickly lose content while the .load function occurs, causing the page to scroll up some. I have tried to show the issue in the gif below. (Try to watch the reload icon in the top, that indicates when the page scrolls to the top)

[image]

**What I Need Fixed**
I need the page to not scroll to the top when new content is loaded or I need a way for the div's that contain the charts to keep their size on reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `css` to set to `width`, `height` properties of the `html` parent element where `html` is loaded to expected `width`, `height` of `html` content, which would not change between `html` content changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fixed css height for #3 and #4 to keep their vertical size.
For example:

```
#3{
    display:block;
    height: 100px;   
}
```

Note: Code not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Put the .js file and other javascript codes that intiates the charts interface (associated with charts) into `3.php` and `4.php` within `<script>` tag.

It works  most of the time.